# Best practice to modify a big pyspark dataframe with single value from another dataframe based on a condition

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have two data frames, one is big and the other is a simple single column/row value. Consider the second dataframe to hold a single value that can act as an upper bound. 
First one is

```py
`+----+-----+-----+----+
|col1|col2 |test1|val. |
+----+-----+-----+----+
|   a|  foo|   p1|  24|
|   b|  bar|   p2|  56|
|   c|  baz|   p3|   8|
+----+-----+-----+----+
```

Second one is with a single value

```py
+--------------+
| upper_bound  |
+--------------+
|25            |
+--------------+
```

I want to add a new boolean column to the first DataFrame by using the `upper_bound` of the second dataframe and a condition (ie: if a single value of `val` is >= `upper_bound`)

Desired output:

```py
+----+-----+-----+----+-----+
|col1|col2 |test1|val |bound|
+----+-----+-----+----+-----+
|   a|  foo|   p1|  24|0    | 
|   b|  bar|   p2|  56|1    |
|   c|  baz|   p3|   8|0    |
+----+-----+-----+----+-----+
```

What is the best way to do this in pyspark? 
Do I get the data out of the second dataframe and use `withColumn` and `filter`?

It is not a good practice to `secondFrame.take(1)[0]['upper_bound']`

Comment: I dont see why I got a downvote for the question. I used simple words and the question is basic and certainly valid for any beginners

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you only have one value, I don't understand why you are saying:

> It is not a good practice to `secondFrame.take(1)[0]['upper_bound']`

I think the faster solution (and more memory parcimoniuous) you can get is, if you know the value for sure,

```py
df.withColumn("bound", psf.col("val")>=psf.lit(25))
```

or if you wan't a more general version,

```py
df.withColumn("bound", psf.col("val")>=secondFrame.take(1)[0]['upper_bound'])
```

If really you don't want to use `secondFrame.take(1)[0]['upper_bound']` which the easiest path, you can do a broadcast join. Something like that could do it:

```py
df2 = rdd.toDF(['upper_bound']).withColumn('dummycol', psf.lit(1))
df  = df.withColumn('dummycol', psf.lit(1))
df  = (df.join(df2, ['dummycol'], how = "left_outer")
          .withColumn("bound", psf.col("val") >= psf.col("upper_bound"))
```

Comment: `upper_bound` value can change.

Comment: But it's always a single value or you have multiple values but a common key with `df` ?

Comment: Yes, example when percentile is calculated from another dataframe's column.

Comment: Ok in that case, I think the best you can do is `df.withColumn("bound", psf.col("val")>=secondFrame.take(1)[0]['upper_bound'])`. The `broadcast` join will work but it's likely to be less efficient